# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

when i try to save a step in the course, i am getting an error
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

> you can download the screenshots using the below urls

[step page details](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqeHwFc2iLKooE4HeBQddOd0KIyR)

when i try to save:

[error page](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqeHwFc2iLKooE9I05IQL_AlbXR_)

my code is

url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.step_details),  
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.course_details),
]
```

models.py:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Step(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
        description = models.TextField()
        order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['order', ]


        def __str__(self):
            self.title
```

views.py:

```
def step_details(request, course_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, course_id = course_pk, pk=step_pk)
    return render(request, 'courses/step_details.html', {'step':step})
```

step_details.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}


{% block title%} {{step.title}} - {{ step.course.title }} {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<article>
<h2> {{ step.course.title }} </h2>
{{ step.description }}
{{ step.content|linebreaks }}
{{ step.course.created_at }}

{##}
{#    <section>#}
{#      {% for step in course.step_set.all %}#}
{#        <h3> {{ step.title}}</h3>#}
{#      {{step.description}}#}
{#      {% endfor %}#}
{#    </section>#}
 </article>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your indentation is wrong, you have written a class inside a class

```
class Course(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Step(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
   description = models.TextField()
   order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ['order', ]


   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

Comment: isn't the ```__str__``` supposed to ```return```?

Comment: @Exprator
Thank you for the response.
i am following a tutorial for learning purposes..
below is the screenshot on how they configured the step process..
class Meta is written inside the Class Step. 

i thought that is how you implement a meta class to a model..

If i missed anything could you please explain..  
  
link for the picture of the configuration (from he tutorial)    
  
[step_meta](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqeHwFc2iLKooFALYmucgft0RaS5)

  __str__ is returning self.tite..